# Specifying how ujson handles serialization of a custom object?

Tags: python, logging, ujson

I have a custom object that I want to log using python's logger module.

I log it with a dict:

```
logger.info({
    'message': 'something happened',
    'object': my_custom_object,
})
```

The problem is logger uses `ujson.dumps()` to serialize the inputs to `logger.info()`.

`ujson.dumps()` converts my_custom_object to a list of the names of instance variables. This isn't very helpful. I want to specify a custom `toJson` or `toDict` method to use when trying to serialize this method instead.

Is this possible?

A bit like how you can specify a `__str__` method and any time python tries to convert your object to string it will call that method instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apparently you *actually can* implement a `toDict` method on the object and it will work.